# Python set operation remove(index)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the below program in python 3.4.3 (.py) script

```
number = {1,2,1,4,5,6,9}
print(number)
number.add(-5)  # adding some random number to the set
number.remove(3) # in this line python reports KeyError
print(number)
number.pop()
print(number)
```

but when i use other index

```
number.remove(2)  # works fine
number.remove(5)  # works fine
```

is there any specific reason why i couldn't use the index 3 to be removed.

Comment: Exact issue reported by python interpreter is KeyError: 3

Comment: Sets don't have indexes. That's not what the `remove` method on a set means.

Comment: (It's not what the `remove` method on a list means either, and lists actually have indexes.)

Comment: `remove` removes a value, not an index. The error is caused because 3 is not in the set.

Comment: The first thing you should do when a method doesn't behave like you expect is to read its documentation. That usually clears up a misunderstanding you have.

Comment: Related: [Difference between del, remove and pop on lists](//stackoverflow.com/q/11520492)

Comment: @ArtemisFowl understood it.

Answer (score 1):

[`remove(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) doesn't remove the item indexed x from the set (sets are unordered in Python), but the element with **value** x:

> `remove(elem)`
>   Remove element elem from the set. Raises KeyError if elem is not contained in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for **[remove(*elem*)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.remove):**

> Remove element *elem* from the set. Raises [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) if elem is not
>   contained in the set.

Therefore, the reason `number.remove(2)`, `number.remove(5)` works and `number.remove(3)` does not is because both `2` and `5` are present in `number` while `3` is not.

---

Note if you do not want to raise a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) you can use **[discard(*elem*)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.discard):**

> Remove element *elem* from the set if it is present.

It also removes an element from a set but does not raise a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#KeyError), if *elem* does not exist.